# Omit portions of the X-Axis on a C# WinForms Chart control

Tags: c#, winforms, charts

Is it possible to "chop up" the X-Axis on a WinForms Chart so instead of starting at 0 to 100 for example, you can segment the axis to start from 0 to 40, skip 40 to 50, and begin again at 51 to 100?

Specifically I am working on a chart where the X-Axis are DateTime values, and I want to skip the weekends so that data from Monday to Friday is displayed next to each other for adjacent weeks graphically instead of having a gap of two days(Saturday and Sunday) between data points.

Thank you.

Comment: You may want to look into 'Empty' points and the options to display/treat them, also into 'Indexed' x-values.

Comment: Indexed x-values provides a better looking graph, the only issue is it seems impossible to grab the data based on X-values when using the Axis.PixelPositionToValue() method. This essentially stops me from displaying coordinate data to the user of the chart as they move the mouse over the inner plot area. The user should be able to get data as the hover the mouse over the chart.

Comment: That is correct. When the x-values are ndexed their actual values are meaningless. You may try to store them in the datapoints and retrieve the datapoints under the mouse with a HitTest instead.